# Best way of spacing out flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to discover the best way of doing the following: I've created a load of navigation links, but when you shrink the screen size, either the space between the flex items can sometimes appear too distant, the '|' symbols that are supposed to go inbetween flex items can appear at the end of a row before the flex item drops to the next line, and (maybe it's my browser) flex items seem to wrap when making the browser wider after shrinking it (i.e. the text inside  tags can be on separate lines.

Is there a good way to fix this? I presumed displaying as a flex with space-between as the content justification would space them out nicely, which it does, but there are a few minor imperfections.

Thanks

```css
.footer-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: pink;
}
.footer-links > a {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background: orange;
}
.footer-links > a:nth-child(n+2) {
  padding: 0 1%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.footer-links > a:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
  background: red;
}
.footer-links > a:first-child {
  padding-right: 1;
  background: lightblue;
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .footer-links { justify-content: center }
}
```

```html
<div class='footer-links'>
  <a>Home</a> | <a>Terms &amp; Conditions</a> | <a>Contact Us</a> | <a>Apps</a> | <a>Some Link</a> | <a>Contact Us</a> | <a>Apps</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Flex box has a "row direction" property. Sounds like what you want. Look it up.

Comment: you mean flex-direction row? this doesn't solve it. If there's such thing as a 'row-direction', I can't find it anywhere on the internet

Comment: Just looked at the result of the posted snippet. What isn't as wanted?

Comment: just a concept: https://jsfiddle.net/6pcx1u7q/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In `.footer-links` I've added `flex-direction: row;` and removed
- I also spotted a mistake in `.footer-links>a:first-child` where it said `padding-right: 1; without the`%` sign.

```css
.footer-links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* added */
  /* justify-content: space-between; */ /* removed */
  flex-wrap: nowrap; /* changed */
  background: pink;
}

.footer-links>a {
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  background: orange;
  white-space: nowrap; /* added */
}

.footer-links>a:nth-child(n+2) {
  padding: 0 1%;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.footer-links>a:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
  background: red;
}

.footer-links>a:first-child {
  padding-right: 1%; /* added the % */
  background: lightblue;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .footer-links {
    justify-content: center
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='footer-links'>
  <a>Home</a> | <a>Terms &amp; Conditions</a> | <a>Contact Us</a> | <a>Apps</a> | <a>Some Link</a> | <a>Contact Us</a> | <a>Apps</a>
</div>
```

---

Also, please consider some changes I made that makes your design a lot nicer. Do with it as you please :)

**[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yv9Lxjo4/15/)**

Comment: thanks, but I don't mind them wrapping. I just wondered whether, when shrinking the browser window, it's possible to make the links not so far apart (e.g. at the point where 2 flex items are on the 2nd line, they appear far away). And that the | symbol is at the very right end of the top line if you know what I mean

Comment: ah so that's what white-space does! btw I think flex wrap should be nowrap, not no-wrap

Comment: @user8758206 you can. just remove your media query, and set the `justify-content` property to center in your footer-links class. No reason to have it set to a specific width if you want it to behave the same way for both scenarios. And your right, it's `nowrap`, but if there are values the agent doesn't recognize (no-wrap) it will use the properties initial value, which just so happens to be `nowrap` in this circumstance which is why they see correct results

Comment: ah I see. And as for the | at the very end of the row, is there any way of getting rid of these if you know what I mean? (hard to explain) i.e. don't show the '|' between one flex item above and the other below

Comment: @user878206 That just has to do with the available space around the items. And you're both right, it should be `nowrap`, I've corrected it.

Comment: @user8758206 Based on your request, and you don't mind them wrapping, does [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/yv9Lxjo4/14/) look like what you wanted? The space is removed between each item. I left the media-query there because I assume you still want the items centered at 1024px+ width. If my answer helped you, please mark it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The flexbox is working the way you told it to work. It's great when robots listen to us!

Your media query explicity states that at anytime before 1024px width, only justify content `space-between`, since that is the value set in the parent class and its inherited. If you want them to be closer then just remove that media query for 1240px+ so it applies to all widths, change the `justify-content` property in the footer-links class to center and it will behave accordingly.

As far as the pipe symbol (`|`), if you don't want it to break lines prior to it's sibling, then don't make it a sibling, and include it with the sibling:

From:

```
<a>Home</a> |
```

To:

```
<a>Home |</a>
```

or better yet, use the `:after` || `:before` psuedo classes, as this [is their intended use](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/generate.html#before-after-content), and is inline by default. Or maybe restructure your code in away that makes more sense, where you use a `<li>` tag with children to display a list of things as you vision, so then it's not child of the parent div (footer-links) and becomes a child of a parent list item. Many opportunities for success here, mostly arbitrary of what you decide, but you should really think about structuring your code, for many reasons like accessibility. Screen readers won't know that your footer-links class is a navigation element by the way in which it's written.

For the sake of answering the question directly, here is an example with psuedo class and center justified content:

```css
.footer-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: pink;
}

.footer-links>a {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background: orange;
}

.footer-links>a:nth-child(n+2) {
  padding: 0 1%;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.footer-links>a:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
  background: red;
}

.footer-links>a:first-child {
  padding-right: 1;
  background: lightblue;
}

/* new change, removed media query and added :after psuedo class for pipes*/
.footer-links a:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "|";
  background: pink;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='footer-links'>
  <a>Home</a><a>Terms &amp; Conditions</a><a>Contact Us</a><a>Apps</a><a>Some Link</a><a>Contact Us</a><a>Apps</a>
</div>
```

Please note, according to the documentation I linked above:

> The :before and :after pseudo-elements inherit any inheritable properties from the element in the document tree to which they are attached.

So you will have to change the background color accordingly in your circumstance

Comment: interesting answer, thanks! But the pseudo-selector of :after seems to only accept padding in px, not %, & ideally I'd like 1%. Also, as for the pipes, I didn't mean hiding the pipe after the very last item, I meant hiding it between the item on the line above and the item below when it drops to the next line after reiszing the browser window

Comment: @user8758206 why can't you use percent? Just because we give you an example doesn't mean you have to use it EXACTLY as it's written, because people who answer questions will never know the full scope of your project. Just tweak it to your needs. Use percent if you want, or don't. Use margin. Use relative position if you want. And where in your question do you mention hiding them? My answer doesn't even attempt to hide anything, all mine does is add pipes to end of every `<a>` tag except the last one which makes sure the pipe doesn't go to a new line before the text does like you requested